# Run maven deploy without re-running the entire build

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm working on a multi-branch pipeline for a maven project. I'm trying to follow what the Jenkins docs keep referring to as the standard CI steps, Build, Test, Deploy. But maven doesn't seem to work very well with treating these as discreet steps.

I have this so far:

```
stages {
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            sh "mvn -B clean verify"
        }
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
        when {
            branch 'master'
        }
        steps {
            sh "mvn -B deploy"
        }
    }
}
```

With this, the full build is going to run twice, once in the `Test` stage and again in the `Deploy` stage. That isn't great as it's a time consuming build thanks to Google Web Toolkit, but that's a separate issue.

Is there a way to gracefully skip the earlier maven lifecycle steps in the `Deploy` stage and skip to the deploy goal?

The only other alternative I can think of is

```
stages {
    stage('Test') {
        when {
            // Some expression that states "not master"
        }
        steps {
            sh "mvn -B clean verify"
        }
    }
    stage('Test-and-Deploy') {
        when {
            branch 'master'
        }
        steps {
            sh "mvn -B deploy"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not happy with that either due to how this is rendered in the Jenkins UI, and it feels odd to compress what the Jenkins documentation implies should be 3 stages into a single stage. I figure it's the lesser evil though, so I'll probably go with that unless I can find something better.

Comment: If you really like to follow the docs than your step `test` is also wrong cause in Maven you compile, package (jar/etc.) and afterwards you do unit testing and the `verify` includes also integration testing if something is defined in Maven build...I would suggest to do the `Test-Deploy` via `mvn -B clean deploy` and in other where you only would like to run tests etc. via `mvn -B clean verify` on the other hand you can try to use only `mvn deploy:deploy` in the separate `deploy` step...But I would recommend not to separate this steps only to follow a documentations...do what best fits..

Comment: it depends a bit on what is done in the lifecycle phases before "deploy". If artifacts are created during one phase and dynamically added to the reactor you're out of luck. What you can try is to just execute the deploy goal instead of the phase: "mvn deploy:deploy" - that might have the result you need.

Comment: Did you eventually get a resolution on this? I'm running into the same problem now, and it's a classic case of _the right way feels wrong_ for me in that I know it should be one stage, but then I lose all the granularity from the UI from before.

Comment: This is just another example of why maven is a very weak tool. Dependency resolution is a madness without plugins, dependency:tree does not match the actual libs that get put into the wars if you have deps through parents, lack of incremental build, not able to execute steps in different commands, etc.... The central repo is awesome though.

Comment: looking for this feature as well - another reason to be annoyed by maven

Answer (score 4):

Maven lifecycle runs all steps that are preconditions to what you execute. Lifecycle looks like this:

```
process-resources
compile
process-test-resources
test-compile
test
package
install
deploy
```

So `compile` will run `process-resources` and so on.

If you want to execute a single goal, you need to specify it using the `plugin:goal` syntax, like this:

`compile:compile`

In your case, to execute only deploy, you need to do `mvn deploy:deploy`.

For detailed description of maven lifecycle and goals, please see the official [docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#setting-up-your-project-to-use-the-build-lifecycle).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a partial answer.

Usually, the most time-consuming part of a build is running the tests. For many projects, skipping that part is already enough to reduce the build time to something acceptable.

In Maven, you can skip the execution of your **unit tests** (which is done by the [Surefire Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/index.html)) like this:

```
mvn deploy -B -DskipTests
```

If your project has **interation tests** (executed by the [Failsafe Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/index.html)), you can skip those as well:

```
mvn deploy -B -DskipTests -DskipITs
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Maven Cache. By default Maven cache in `~/.m2` directory. It depends how you setup your Jenkins Agent/Slave. It is possible to have Maven cache inside Jenkins Agent and reuse the cache when Maven run `deploy` and it can save significant amount of build time.